# How to send BNB to multiple address without using for loop

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethers.js, nodejs, sendtransaction

I need to send BNB or BSC tokens to multiple addresses. I saw some answers but they are used for loop. I can't use a loop because it takes a lot of time and the server is not responding. Is there any method to solve this process?

I'm trying the node-js **sendTransaction** method but there is no chance to send multiple addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You could submit a flashbot bundle (https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/advanced/understanding-bundles) (EDIT : Oops, no, they don't exist on the BSC) Or use a smart contract for that. Here's an example for ETH

```
contract Sender {
  function sendETHToAddresses(address[] calldata to, uint[] calldata values) external payable {
    require(to.length == values.length, "mismatched inputs");
    // inefficient,do the check in JS before sending 
    /* 
    uint sum;
    for(uint i; i < values.length; ++i) {
      sum += values[i];
    }
    require(sum <= msg.value, "Not enough ETH");
    */
    for(uint i; i < values.length; ++i) {
      (bool os, ) = payable(to[i]).call{value: values[i]}(new bytes(0));
      require(os, "transfer failed");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's solidity? And ur using  for loop. I think it takes lot of time.

Comment: It is solidity, yes. And no, that would be only one transaction, so you're eliminating your sever issue

Comment: So I first need to write solidity (for multiple addresses send Process ) right?
And I can't solve this process without writing solidity right?